# Spring boot - Docker logs

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, docker

I have a spring boot java application running inside a docker container. I configured logback in the application. Where i can access the generated logs? The configured path is:

```
<property name="LOG_PATH" value="logs"/>
```

I am currently checking logs using: docker logs containerName --follow 
But this command return the current logs from the last time the application was started. How can i check the rolling logs or archived ones.

Is there a way to create a volume for logback logs?

Comment: Check this, it may help : https://fabianlee.org/2017/03/21/docker-sending-spring-boot-logging-to-syslog/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am using the following way: in logback.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<property name="LOG_PATH" value="logs"/>
<timestamp key="currentTimestamp" datePattern="yyyy-MM-dd'_'HH"/>

<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>
            %d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %magenta([%thread]) %highlight(%-5level) %logger.%M\(%line\) - %msg%n
        </pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="SAVE-TO-FILE"
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_PATH}/appName.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>
            %d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36}.%M - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- the rollover occurs when the active log file reaches the maximum file size before the end of the time period. -->
        <!-- The rollover period is inferred from the smallest date unit value of fileNamePattern -->
        <!-- each file should be at most [maxFileSize], keep [maxHistory] days worth of history, but at most [totalSizeCap] -->
        <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
        <fileNamePattern>
            ${LOG_PATH}/archived/appName.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
        </fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        <totalSizeCap>1GB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>


<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    <appender-ref ref="SAVE-TO-FILE"/>
</root>
```

In docker run :

```
docker run --network name-network --restart=unless-stopped --name name-java-container 
--hostname valueOfHostname -d -p 8080:8080 \
-v /data/nameFolderForLogs:/logs \
imageName
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to implement your file-appender with

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <property name="LOG_PATH" value=/var/app>
    ...
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender"> 
        <file>${LOG_PATH}/spring.log</file>
        ...   
    </appender>
</configuration>
```

And after this you can run the next command:

```
docker exec -it containerName cat /var/app/spring.log > $HOME/spring.log
```

or make volume with `(docker run ... -v "$HOME/app:/var/app")`

Comment: If I updated my springboot project ad update the image, will I lose my log file?

Comment: Hi, @NothingBox! I'm sorry for the late reply! If you dont wanna lose the logs and you use docker exec command to save logs with '>' as i it showed in my post, then you _need to change the operation from '>' to '>>' (append)_. But if you use _docker volumes, be sure everything will be fine_ without changes! ;)

Comment: I am not redirecting it using > $HOME/spring.log. The tail just works.